# How to manually insert and remove a child View (not triggering render) in a react native component?

Tags: react-native

Sometimes it's more convenient/efficient to manually insert/remove a child view than to trigger a re-render in a component ? I.e, in a canvas that needs to frequently insert a message that floats from right to left, then after the animation it got removed.

Question is how should I do that ?

Thanks a lot for your help : )

Answer (score 0):

After seeing this post: http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-periscope-hearts-animation/, I think I got the anwser.